# Get start and end postion of a text selection with sourrounded elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a "annotation" tool - the user can surround some elements in a text (in a div). I need to keep the selection ranges positions of the RAW text.

With this div containing text to annotate:

```html
<div id="annotate">foo bar baz</div>
```

Using `document.getSelection()`, and `getRangeAt()` it possible to use `surroundContents()` that works. But the problem is that, after having surrounding the first label, I cannot get the "real" text position of the second selection.

After surrounded elements:

```html
<div id="annotate">foo <span class="tag">bar</span> baz</div>
```

If I select "baz", the `anchorStart` is 0 instead of 8. That's becauces the "anchorNode" is now a TextNode because there is now a span injected from the `surroundContents()` method.

I don't find any solution to get the selection position using only the "div" raw content.

NOTE: I tried Rangy library to check if it gives a solution, but no...
I also checked how doccano interface does the job, but the code is a bit complicated to decrypt so the method is not easy to understand.

This is an example:

```js
function annotate() {
  let selection = document.getSelection();
  let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  
  let pre = document.querySelector("pre");
  pre.innerHTML = `start: ${range.startOffset}`;
  
  let annotation = document.createElement("span");
  annotation.classList.add("box");
  range.surroundContents(annotation);
  
  
  selection.empty();
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: yellow
}
#annotator {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Try first to select "bar" and annotate. Then select "baz" and annotate. You'll see that the startOffset will be 1.
</p>
<div id="annotator">foo bar baz</div>
<button onclick="annotate()">annotate</button>

<pre>results...</pre>
```

A special note: I currently make regexp "matchAll" iteration on the parent element "innerHTML" to get index of found tag, remove tag length, and continue. That works but it's not very efficient.

Comment: Just iterate over all the children of the div before that text node and add the sum of their length to it, no?

Comment: It could have subchildren. That's not how does doccano for example. For now I do approximately what you say, regexp and add length of the matched tags.

Comment: That's not what I meant. (see the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the highlighted text does not contain any already-highlighted region (otherwise `surroundContents` would not work anyway):

- Use `const startContainer = range.startContainer` to get the text node that contains the whole range. (this should be the same as `range.endContainer`)
- Find the index of it inside the `annotator` div: `const index = [...annotator.childNodes].indexOf(startContainer)`
- The actual start offset is `range.startOffset` + the sum of the lengths of the previous nodes (`annotator.childNodes[0]`, `annotator.childNodes[1]`, ..., `annotator.childNodes[index-1]`)
- To compute the text length of a node, use `node.nodeValue.length` for `Text` nodes, or `node.innerText.length` for `<span>` nodes.

Alternatively:

- Store the start offset of each node with respect to the original div in an attribute/property of the node.
- For each added node, compute the new offset for the inside text span(s) and the immediately-after text node.
- Use that offset to adjust the local offset in each node.

This way you don't have to iterate through all the children to get the offset; however for most practical purposes the number of children is negligible.

Comment: That's what I do at this time but that's not efficient and there could have already surrounded texts. Even if it's a valid answer (it works like this at this time on my project), it seems that others projets doesn't make the job this way. Doccano is a good example, but the method is hard to understand. But thanks to confirm that my first approach is more or less like your idea 

Comment: @Metal3d Not efficient? I feel that it's very efficient. (even if there are 1000 selected regions already, computers can iterate through them very quickly.) Or do you have some other special requirements?

Comment: @Metal3d Are you sure you understood the answer correctly? That would work regardless whether there's surrounded text; also my method doesn't involve regex at all.

Comment: Yes, thanks... I understand and I repeat that what I see on others interface isn't the same method. I use regexp to make code simpler,. I already make iteration to sum tag size when I find elements, and so on... One more time, here were are "parsing" element while the others interfaces seems to get a better method using chunks. Better because it seems to not make some special things to have nested ranges.

Comment: I make precision, the only difference between your explanation and mine is that you use the Range "parent" element to have the beginning, when I use the parent outerHTML to get "span" regexp. The method remains the same: we count element size and sum with previous to have next position.